# How to apply CSS setting to specific HTML element

Tags: html, css

***HTML:***

```
        <div class="tagline">Web Portal Name</div><br />
        <div id="logged_in_user_dtls" style="color:#FFF; margin-top:15px; font:bold; width:100%; position:relative; margin-left:800px;float:left;">

      <span> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['userName'] ?> </span>
       | <a href="login.php"><span> Sign Out</a> </span> </div>
```

In my web templete, I'm displaying logged in user name followed by welcome message.

**Problem:** When My user name is long(approx 30 char) my next link which is (sign out link), is moved to right hand side.

How can I avoid moving this Sign out link to the right. I know it may have simple answer but unable to figure it out.

Note: I tried to change marigin-left setting, but its spoiling my alignment.

**Update:**
Can I keep Sign out link's position fixed, irrespective of user name lenght?

Comment: | <a href="login.php"><span> Sign Out</span> </a> close in correct format it will work automatically. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/YF6xC/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but still problem is there. Still link moves.

Answer (score 0):

Set a max-width for long names and put an ellipsis to show this:

```
<span class="username"> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['userName'] ?> </span>
```

### CSS

```
.username  {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: x px; /* set this to what you need */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#logged_in_user_dtls span {
   width: 200px; /* adjust that to your needs*/
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will make the longer parts of the name cut. You could remove the `overflow:hidden;` if you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
span{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
max-width:xx px;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
}
```